# how can I read something from Laravel command into my controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-4

Thanks to be advised that I have created a new laravel command that runs periodically through the schedule function.

Here in the handle function, I am performing this query every day and I want to be able to retrieve the variable topics in a get method in my controller. So what is the best way to conduct this?

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $topics = DB::table("sentences")
            ->select("topic")
            ->OrderByRaw("RAND()")
            ->distinct()
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
        echo($topics);    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no links between the command you execute here and your controllers.

There are no ways to "retrieve" the `$topics` variable inside a controller, they are totally distinct entities in your application.

My guess is that you are trying to cache these data so you can get them quickly, without any performance problem.

If this is the case, then you are lucky because the solution is pretty simple.

```php
    public function handle()
    {
        Cache::put('topics', function(){
           return DB::table("sentences")
              ->select("topic")
              ->OrderByRaw("RAND()")
              ->distinct()
              ->limit(5)
              ->get();
        });
  
        return 0;
    }
```

Then, anywhere in your application, you'll be able to retrieve the topics by doing:

```php
$topics = Cache::get('topics');
```

This is a basic example but it should work. However, if the cache doesn't exist, `Cache::get('topics')` will return `null`.

You can solve this problem by retrieving the topics with:

```php
$topics = Cache::rememberForever('topics', function(){
           return DB::table("sentences")
              ->select("topic")
              ->OrderByRaw("RAND()")
              ->distinct()
              ->limit(5)
              ->get();
        });

// this way, if the cache doesn't exist, it'll be created.
// then your scheduled command will update it every day
```

Comment: I updated my answer because the code had some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$topics = DB::table("sentences")
            ->select("topic")
            ->OrderByRaw("RAND()")
            ->distinct()
            ->limit(5)
            ->pluck('id');  //pass only the array if ids
if($topics) 
  return redirect()->route('route.name.to.controller',['topics' => $topics]);
else
   // do another action
```